# All nested menus show when hovering over menu instead of just the first

Tags: css

I have used this method to centrally align my menu: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

I am having problems though with my selectors.  The selectors I am using to show the sub menu and style the links is applying to all nested tags.

I have read the `+` operator selects the next sibling but I've tried things like `#menu-main-menu-container li:hover a + ul` but it doesn't work.  The hover selector is confusing me a bit.

I included the snippet below.  Can someone show me how I should be just selecting the first occurrence to display when hovering over the `li`?

I also have a problem of the second nested submenu not aligning properly but I think that might be due to the way I have centred the menu and not sure if that is fixable or not.

Any help appreciated.

```css
#menu-main-menu-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font: 300 16px/16px Lato, Arial; }
  #menu-main-menu-container ul {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
    #menu-main-menu-container ul ul {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      margin-top: 15px; }
      #menu-main-menu-container ul ul ul {
        right: 0; }
  #menu-main-menu-container ul li {
    right: 50%;
    background-color: #f4f4f4; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    #menu-main-menu-container li:hover ul {
      display: block; }
  #menu-main-menu-container a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    transition: 1s; }
  #menu-main-menu-container li:hover a {
    color: white; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="top-nav-menu.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu-main-menu-container">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hidden Sub Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with:

```
#menu-main-menu-container li:hover > ul
```

## Operator `>`

If you use `>` operator you ensure that `ul` must be direct child of `li:hover`.

Comment: Cool thanks.  That fixed it.  Just need to work out the positioning now :)